# Return statement with try/catch

Tags: java, android, return, try-catch

I know that for many of you this can be a stupid question, but I'm learning android/java and I still have some concepts unclear.

In this case, I'm not sure on what is the best way to use the return statement within a try/catch block.

This is how I have declared my method where I need to use this:

```
public JSONArray parseXmlResponse(String response) {

        JSONArray addressComp = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            addressComp = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addressComp;
    }
```

As far as I know, here the method is always returning "addressComp", even if it is null.
But I've seen that other people would do it in this other way:

```
public JSONArray parseXmlResponse(String response) {

        JSONArray addressComp = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            addressComp = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");
            return addressComp;
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But this makes me a bit confused.
By setting the `return null` here won't set the value to return always as null even if addressComp has a real value?

Comment: If no exception occurs, then the return happends at the end of the `try` block. At that point `addressComp` is returned, which is not null.

Comment: `return null;` is unreachable code.

Comment: @Petter So, as you say, if no exceptions occur and it goes through the try block, it returns what is in the try block and jumps over the return null value

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun No, it is not. If one of the statements in the try block throws a JSONException, it will not reach the `return addressComp;` and will therefore reach `return null;` after printing the stacktrace.

Comment: @blalasaadri You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Setting the return null there won't set the value to return always as null even if addressComp has a real value?

No, once it hits the first `return` statement it will `return addressComp` and the `return null` line will never be executed. Just be sure you check for `null` on the variable that is taking that value if it will cause problems.

**Edit**

```
JSONArray jArray = parseXmlResponse(someString);
if (jArray != null)
{
     //run some code
}
else
{
    //it's null so run some other code
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the next thing should be to set another try/catch block to catch NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION where the variable takes ta value, right?

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily need to be a `try/catch` block. Let me edit with a short example

Answer (score 1):

These methods achieve essentially the same thing. In the second way, it will only reach the return statement...

```
return addressComp;
```

... if everything above it in the try block is fine and doesnt throw an exception. Once this is hit, the method is complete and no more code is executed, so it would not reach the null return.

If, however, something goes wrong in the try block, it will go to catch, print the stack trace, and then program flow will fall through the try catch block, and return the null value. Note that as soon as the exception is thrown, NOTHING else in the try block will be run.

The second method is a little bit nicer because you can at least report issues. If you use the first way, you would want to check if the returned value is null before proceeding.